# How do I make text appear in text field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out how to output text in a textfield in HTML. I've looked at many solutions and although I'm very close (I think I am), I still can't get it to function properly.

I'm trying to sort a series of numbers by separating them with "; " and wish to show the result in the bottom text field by ascending or descending order. The action is done by pressing the button to sort them.

When trying to debug it, it seems that the variables are being assigned their values as they should, but the variable "output" just won't show up in the "Sorted Numbers" textfield. My code is incomplete as I'm just trying to test this for an ascending order before I add in the descending order.

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Sorting Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>


        Enter Numbers Here: <input type = "text" id = "numInput"><br><br>
        Select Option:      <select id = "menu">
                                <option value = "ascending">Ascending</option>
                                <option value = "descending">Descending</option>
                            </select><br><br>
        Sorted Numbers: <input type = "text" id = "numOut"><br><br>
        <button onclick = "sortNums()">Sort Numbers</button>


    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function sortNums() {
            var choice = document.getElementById("menu");
            var numbers = document.getElementById("numInput").value;
            var output = document.getElementById("numOut").value;

            if(choice.value = "ascending") {
                arr  = numbers.split('; ').sort().join('; ');
                output = arr;
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script doesn't magically know, what you want to do with the value, you've to tell it ...

Comment: Your script is working fine and doing exactly what you tell it to. It creates three variables (choice, numbers, output), assigns their value, and sorts them, assigning the new order to a variable (arr). It then assigns the value of arr to the variable output. If you want output to show up you have to tell it to show up (see Spencer's answer below).

Comment: Thanks guys! I guess it was just a misconception I had on how these methods function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you never assigned `output` to it afterwards:

```
if(choice.value = "ascending") {
    arr  = numbers.split('; ').sort().join('; ');
    output = arr;
    document.getElementById("numOut").value = output; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I just don't understand why writing the line output = arr; doesn't do the same thing as the line you've written in the if block. I only assigned the variable output to that just to make it look a bit cleaner. However, since it worked the way you typed it out for me, I might as well just cut out "output" completely and have 

document.getElementById("numOut").value = arr;

Comment: @Dude420 Because `output` just contains the value of the element, and as such is not directly related. Think of it has changing the property of an object. For example I could say I have `obj.x`, if was say `var y = obj.x` and change `y` it will not change `obj.x`, the only way would be doing it directly `obj.x = newValue`.

Comment: I see, makes more sense, now thanks again for your help!